# Using Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Elastichsearch in same app with same Domain Object

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-data-elasticsearch

I've got a Spring Boot application that utilizes Spring Data JPA to implement a REST-based service. Now I wish to add full text search functionality using Spring Data ElasticSearch. I'm using the latest release version of everything from Spring.

I've defined the JPA repositories and the ElasticSearch repositories in different packages that are siblings to each other, example.repository.jpa and example.repository.es. I've marked the ElasticSearch repository with `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)` since I don't wish to expose the ES stuff via REST.

The ES repository is defined as an interface that extends `ElasticsearchRepository<Domain, Long>` and has nothing else in it.

The issue I'm running into is that when I boot the app, Spring Data Rest seems to be confused and is somehow losing the fact that it should be exposing the JPA repositories. I've tried setting

`@EnableJpaRepositories("example.repository.jpa")
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "example/repository/es")`

on the main application class in order to try to narrow the configuration, but nothing is working.

The Domain object is marked as `@Entity` and `@Document` and is a fairly simple POJO.

Has anyone every successfully used both Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Elasticsearch with the same Domain object in the same application? Does anyone have any example code/configuration they can share or point me to? Is this even the right way to go?

Comment: What error are you getting or what are your expecting v/s what are you seeing?  Can you post a small sample somewhere for others to try and investigate?

Comment: Well, basically, once I create a ES-based Repository for the same Domain object, and hit the Spring Data Rest endpoint for the resource to see the list of HAL metadata, everything from the JPA Repository implementation is gone. Any of the methods that were working to query or modify a resource via SDR no longer work, and generally through an error about the HTTP method not being supported. There are no error messages in the application log or anything, just the difference in behavior. As soon as I remove the ES repository interface, everything goes back to normal.

Comment: We have a similar case where parts of product information need to be stored in an RDBMS (basic product information), MongoDB (product code and name + dynamic attributes) and Solr (all searchable fields).  We have created a `BaseProduct(id, code, name, brand)`, `@Entity Product extends BaseProduct` (RDBMS), `@Document ProductDetails extends BaseProduct` (MongoDB) and `@Indexed ProductIndex extends BaseProduct` (Solr).  Each has its own repository.  Would something like this work for you?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I will try that and see if it works, though in my use case, I pretty much want to index everything in the Domain object. Another interesting thing I've seen is that it appears that the JPA Repository implementation is being used when make calls to the Search Repository interface. I switched to using the SolrRepository implementation, and I'm seeing the same issue. So it appears that Spring Data is indeed being confused by having the same Domain object. It appears you cannot share the Domain object across Repository implementations.

Comment: Actually, a simple extension of the model won't work, because the @Indexed attribute (or the @Field) attribute for Solr can only be applied at the attribute level. It cannot be applied to methods. Your solution only works if you are truly splitting your data across the storage solutions, but not actually duplicating the data. I'm my case, I'm simply trying to implement a simple Full Text search capability, but I want my system of record to be the RDBMS.

Comment: Have you tried `@MappedSuperclass class BaseProduct { @Column @Indexed private String name; ... }`, `@Entity class Product extends BaseProduct`, `@Document class ProductIndex extends BaseProduct`?  It is perfectly fine adding store-specific annotations to base class fields since we have that for our `BaseProduct`.  It will be better if you post a sample somewhere so that people can try.

Comment: Yes, I have @MappedSuperclass on the base class. It seems that all I needed was to have the subclass as the item that is tied to the Repository. Its empty otherwise. I'll have to work on building an example that I can post, as the code I have is tied in to too many other aspects of my app to be runnable. It definitely seems like Spring Data is confused when two different types of repository interfaces want to consume the same Domain object. As soon as I have an example, I'll post it and probably open an issue in the Spring Data JIRA.

Comment: I've created an issue in the Spring Data Commons project, https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-726 to document the issue. Its either a bug with Spring Data JPA (I think), or something that should be more clearly documented/discussed in the reference site. The issue also has the link to a Github repo that demonstrates the current issues.

Comment: I have added a comment on the JIRA issue.  Do take a look when you get a chance.